# Polynomial Functions and Evaluations

Tags: functions, polynomials

I'm using a website to website based program for a math class and I need help on one section of it.

How it works is you are given a set of problems to answer and once you answer them all, at the bottom of the page there are a set of instructions on what to do with the answers with which you enter into the url and go to the next "site". It goes without saying that if you do not calculate the correct number to put into the url, you are not able to move on to the next page. I also need this help before Monday. Thanks guys.

1. Find the real roots of the equation: $x^6 - 9x^3 + 8 = 0$
2. Solve the equation: $(x-4)^2  - (x-4) = 20$
3. Solve the equation: $x^4 + 5x^2 + 4 = 0$
4. One of the solutions of the equation $(x^3 + 3x^2 + 9x + 27 = 0)$  is $3i$. Find the remaining solutions.
5. Find the solutions to the equation: $2x^5 - 20x^3 + 18x = 0$.

TO ADVANCE: Square the product of the answers to question #4. Multiply this result by the sum of the remaining answers. Take the absolute value of this amount and add $729$.

Here are the answers I've gotten, and the number I've calculated to advance to the next page.

1. $x=1$, and $x=2$
2. $x=9$, and $x=0$
3. $x= -i, x= i, x= -2i, x= 2i$
4. $x= -3i, x= 3i, x= -3$
5. $-3, -1, 0, 3, 1$

$(3i*-3i*-3) = -27 (-27^2) = 729$

$(1+2+9+0+-3+-1+0+1+3+-i+i+2i+-2i) = 12$

$|-729*12| = 8748$

$8748+729 = 9477$

I included my calculations in case it could be useful in determining what I'm doing wrong and to find the proper answer.

Comment: You can check all such straight-forward computations on a site like [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but the real root in #4 should be $-3$ not $3$.

Comment: @Lovsovs I have checked the calculations but something is still missing.

Comment: @Mr.Robot Check the real sign at #4. A polynomial with all the coefficients being positive cannot have a positive real root.

Comment: @Arby I actually do have it as -3, it was just an overlooked mistake in my typing. But thank you

Comment: @Mr.Robot It doesn't change the end result, but `Square the product of the answers to question #4.` that should be $(-27)^2=729\,$.

Comment: @dxiv yeah you're right, thanks

Comment: @Mr.Robot Or maybe I am not right after all. `Find the remaining solutions.` The ***remaining*** solutions are just $-3i,-3\,$. `Square the product of the answers to question #4.` That could be interpreted as $\left((-3i) \cdot (-3)\right)^2=-81\,$. Though I'd say it's a rather lame wordplay.

Comment: @dxiv dude you are completely right, that was the answer. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to some insight, on the absolute garbage wording of this program, from @dxiv,  the calculated answer is 1701!